# How to Display the value of object in the combobox?

Tags: extjs

When I am trying to fetch data from the Store in the Combo Box,I am getiing output as--- [object Object]!!! but the value of the object is not coming!! Can any body tell me what is the problem or what should be the solution for this???

Comment: How are you trying to print the output?

Comment: Code of what you have so far please.

Comment: (1)Model

Ext.define('AM.model.States', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {type: 'string', name: 'abbr'},
            {type: 'string', name: 'name'},
            {type: 'string', name: 'slogan'}
        ]
    });

Comment: (2)Store

states1=Ext.define('AM.store.States', {
 extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
 model : 'AM.model.States',
 data : store

});

var store = [ {"abbr":"AL","name":"Alabama","slogan":"The Heart of Dixie"},
                {"abbr":"AK","name":"Alaska","slogan":"The Land of the Midnight Sun"},
                {"abbr":"AZ","name":"Arizona","slogan":"The Grand Canyon State"},
              ];

Comment: (3)View

items : [{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    name: 'States', 
                    fieldLabel: 'State',
            store: states1,
                  submitValue : true,
                    valueField: 'abbr',
                    displayField: 'abbr',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    forceSelection: true
                },

Answer (score 1):

In Extjs 4.0:

1. Create data model

   ```
   Ext.define('Bond', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       idProperty: 'userid',
       fields: [                        
           {
               name :'industryGroupsreName',
               type:'string'
           }, 
       ]
   });
   ```
2. Create store

   ```
   var industry=new Ext.data.Store(
   {
       model:'Bond',
       proxy: 
       {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: 'industry.html',        
           reader: {
               type: 'json'
           }
       }                    
   });
   industry.load();
   ```
3. Apply bellow code to your combo box

   ```
   new  Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', 
   {
       fieldLabel: 'Industry Group Name',
       store: industry,                            
       id: "industrygroup",
       name: "industrygroup",                            
       allowBlank: false,
       hiddenName : 'industrygroup',
       width:300,
       queryMode: 'local',
       displayField: 'industryGroupsreName',
       valueField: 'industryGroupsreName'                         
   }),
   ```

Comment: I am using the Store like this:------states1=Ext.define('AM.store.States', { extend : 'Ext.data.Store', model : 'AM.model.States', data : store }); var store = [ {"abbr":"AL","name":"Alabama","slogan":"The Heart of Dixie"}, {"abbr":"AK","name":"Alaska","slogan":"The Land of the Midnight Sun"}, {"abbr":"AZ","name":"Arizona","slogan":"The Grand Canyon State"}, ];                    Then it is giving error as:--""Cannot call method 'getProxy' of undefined??? Can you tell me what's the problem!!!